# How do I fix this for loop I did for a jTable?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtable

I just did a button that adds products from a jComboBox, the quantity we want from a jTextField and the price of the product in a jTable.

I want my button to add the product, and if it's already in the jTable, it just adds the quantity we want to the right column. It works for the first product I have, but not the rest.

```
    String cp = jComboBoxProduit.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //CategorieCombo is a class that gives us the id, value or price of a row in a SQL table
    CategorieCombo pp = (CategorieCombo) jComboBoxProduit.getSelectedItem();
    DefaultTableModel leModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable4.getModel();
    

            if(jTable4.getRowCount() != 0)
            {   
                for (int i = 0; i < jTable4.getRowCount(); i++)
                {
                if ((String)jTable4.getValueAt(i, 0) != cp)
                {
                    leModel.addRow(new Object[]{cp, jTextFieldQuantity.getText(), pp.getPrix()});
                }
                else {
                int qte = Integer.valueOf(jTable4.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
                qte = qte + Integer.valueOf(jTextFieldQuantity.getText());
                jTable4.setValueAt(qte, i, 1);
                }
                }
            }        
            else         
            {
            leModel.addRow(new Object[]{cp, jTextFieldQuantity.getText(), pp.getPrice()});
            }
```

I think it doesn't work because the following line

```
leModel.addRow(new Object[]{cp, jTextFieldQuantity.getText(), pp.getPrix()});
```

it's in the for loop, so maybe it just execute everytime there is a row in my table, but I'd like if I could just execute this line once.

I hope I've been clear enough, thanks if you can help me find the answer !

Comment: Don't use "!=" for object comparison. Instead use the `equals(...)` method. Also, it is usually easier to do a test in the positive sense. That is if (true) doSomething else doSomethingElse. And use proper language when asking a question.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to see clearer, but unfortunately the problem is still there. Thanks for helping me tho !

Comment: *so maybe it...* - don't guess what it is doing. Add debug code. Display code so you can tell when the if or else statement is executed. Display the value from the table and the value from the combo box to make sure you are comparing the proper object. This is what programming is about. We can't tell you the answer because 1) the code is not executable and 2) we don't have access to your data.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that, thanks. I'm a beginner at programming so I still have some problems at resolving problem by myself.